# How to allow public read data from Kinvey, but authenticated access on create/edit/delete

Tags: security, authorization, kinvey

I set "shared privacy" for [collections privacy](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular/guides/security#Collectionlevelpermissions) (only owner may edit/delete - Bob).

If other user (Alice) authenticated, she may view Bob's records correctly.
But if Eve (unregistered user) wants to read Bob's record, she gets an error:

```
{
  name: "NoActiveUser",
  description: "You need to be logged in to execute this request."
}
```

What should I do to allow Eve access Bob's record?

Thanks